# Wannier's solution of the Landau-Zener problem

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mathematical-physics, specific-reference

It is said that Wannier had a very simple solution of the Landau-Zener problem. His paper is on Physics 1, 251 (1965). Apparently this journal is closed and I cannot find the paper online.

Does anyone know his solution?

Comment: By *whom* is that said, and what's the title of the paper?

Comment: @ACuriousMind   From the literature. I cannot get that paper, so the title is unknown.

Comment: Is the paper "Probability of violation of the Ehrenfest principle in fast passage"? That is the one elusive paper that I see from 1965.

Comment: @RazimanT.V.  I do not know. But it seems the right one.

Comment: @RazimanT.V.  Yes. It is! But I still cannot download it.

Comment: Seems that it is not available online. But some university libraries should have a copy.